# Primavera login problems P6 R8.2 proffisional

Tags: windows-7, database, primavera

I just installed Primavera P6 R8.2 on windows 7 successfully.

I don't know the reason for why not login in,  I have MS SQL is 2005 , oracle 10g, SQL command line avilable

the only password installed is (Prima123Vera) at beginning of installation, so no Idea about other passwords or keys.

I want to start the program by any user & password available.

As I found pubuser is not available.

any data required I may help you can tell.

I have time to follow instructions on cmd or sql to set on the passwords & users

Comment: Is this install from the original source with the correct login or from a torrent?

Comment: not sure from the source but it is transferred program